# Как реализовать счетчик в плагине jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Поставила себе задачу:
Плагин меняющий текст элемента по клику, данные берет из пользовательского массива. Эдакий toggle text (Изъяснилась наверное сухо, но на примере ниже думаю будет понятно)

```
$('.slowpock').toggleText(['text','text2','text3'])
```

Проблема возникла в реализации замыкания. Не могу понять как реализовать этот самый счетчик в рамках jquery плагина (опыта маловато ^-^).

То что имею на данный момент:

```js
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.toggleText = function(text) {
    if (arguments.length < 0) {
      return false;
    }

    var counter = 1; /*:(*/

    return this.each(function() { 
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.html(text[0])

    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.toggleText = function(text) {
     // ... some checks
    
     var counter = 0; /*:)*/
   
     this.click(function() { 
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.html(text[counter++]);
       if (counter >= text.length)
         counter = 0; 
     });
   
     return this;
  };
})( jQuery );

$("div").toggleText(["One", "Two", "Three"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>start 1</div>
<div>start 2</div>
```

Comment: Мне кажется этот вариант не пройдет.. counter будет обновлять к нулю каждый клик. (Только что протестировала ваш вариант, хотя ваш кодстайл  изящен. Я пока пишу более громоздко)

Comment: @AnnaKamardiner Взгляните на работающий пример. Вам нужна сквозная ротация строк текста, или для каждого элемента в выборке - своя?

Comment: О, а обновленный вариант меня порадовал )) Спасибо.

Comment: Да сквозная ратация самое то

Comment: Ну суть я уловила, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($){
  $.fn.toggleText = function(text) {
    if (arguments.length < 0) return false;
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      // Счетчик у каждого элемента свой. поэтому кладём внутрь цикла.
      var counter = 0;
      $this.click(e => {
          if(counter >= text.length) counter = 0;
          $this.html(text[counter++]);
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('.slowpock').toggleText(['text','text2','text3'])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='slowpock'>test1</div>
<div class='slowpock'>test2</div>
```

Comment: Про счетчик хорошее замечание, спасибо.

Comment: а если нужно чтобы событие клик было из-вне:
` $('span').click(function() { $(this).toggleText(['1', '2']) });`

Comment: @AnnaKamardiner `$('span').click();`